# Как проще всего реализовать функцию "похожие статьи"?

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу сделать вывод похожих статей. Есть таблица статей, ну допустим с именем, articles с полями id, text, title и т.д. 
Делать запроc like каждый раз при просмотре статьи слишком ресурсоемко. Поэтому нужно как-то id-шники похожих на данную статей записывать в БД. И оттуда вытаскивать их JOIN запросом. А добавлять эти id при каждом создании или редактировании статьи.

Как я понимаю в mysql нет функции split для строки. Поэтому напрашивается вывод, что добавление varchar-столбца типа likes к этой таблице дело не решит. Есть идея сделать отдельную таблицу с полями `news_id` и `news_likes_id`. И уже туда записывать id'шники всех похожих статей. Т.е. для каждой статьи например будет соответствовать несколько строк:

```
news_id   news_likes_id
  1            5
  1            6
  1            4
  4            5
...
```

Надеюсь понятно все изложил. Может у вас есть другие идеи?

Comment: Такие вещи обычно делают через метки. А по контенту схожесть можно выявлять только если используется система индексирования типа [sphinx][1].

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_(%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Comment: Ну можно и самому сделать похожесть :) Только вот действительно надо ли оно ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если "Как проще всего" то сделайте еще две таблицы:

```
tags
id | tag

tag_article
id | tag_id | article_id
```

и в каждой статье нужно проставить эти тэги.

Ну а похожие - это выбрать статьи в которых есть данные тэги, исключая текущую.

допустим curId - это текущий id статьи.

```
select article_id from tag_article where tag_id in (select tag_id from tag_article where article_id = curId) and article_id <> curId
```

вот мы и получили список "похожых" статей.

Comment: Спасибо. Насчет тэгов я как-то не подумал. Теперь понятно... Еще покопаюсь в популярных cms, может там че найду хорошего)

Comment: А можно у вас совета спросить? Лучше же наверное сделать поле tag (в таблице tags) как primary, нет? Ну чтобы одинаковые тэги не писались в эту таблицу...

Comment: Нет, primary это id

а поле tag лучше сделать unique

Comment: Вот блин))) Забыл про существование Unique вообще)) Спасибо, тёзка))